# Is the starting value $k$ ensure convergence for almost all polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, convergence-divergence, roots, examples-counterexamples, newton-raphson

It's a follow up of [Does three iteration are sufficient to use Newton's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883613/does-three-iteration-are-sufficient-to-use-newtons-method)

Come back on the previous question :

$f(x)=x\left(b_0(1+x)+\frac{b_1}{x+1}+\frac{b_2}{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}+\cdots+\frac{b_{n}}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\cdots x}}}}\right)-C=0\tag{I}$

Or:

$x\left(b_{0}\left(x+1\right)+b_{1}\cdot\frac{1}{x+1}+b_{2}\frac{x+1}{x+2}+b_{3}\cdot\frac{x+2}{2x+3}+\cdot\cdot+\frac{b_{n}\left(F_{n-2}x+F_{n-1}\right)}{F_{n-1}x+F_{n}}\right)-C=0$

Where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci's numbers

> > Now let $b_0\geq 1,C>2$,$b_i\in R$

Using Newton's method on $f(x)$ provided the  polynomial (numerator)  have only one positive real root over $R^+$

> > Is the starting value $k>x_{positive-root}$ with the Newton's methods  sufficient to ensure the convergence to the positive and unique root ?

Have you a proof or a counterxample ?

Comment: We can use the lower bound as Cauchy's inequality see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

Using the Kantorovitch's theorem we need to show $x,y,k>0$:

$$|f'(x)-f'(y)|<k|x-y|\tag{I}$$

But by definition of $f(x)$ we have :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)-ax+b=0,a>0$$

So taking $k$ sufficiently large for all $x>M>0$ we have $I$.

If so taking a sufficiently large initial value we have convergence .

Conclusion :

Excluding the too small value invoking divergence we have for sufficiently large one as application of the Kantorovitch's theorem the convergence is reached.

Reference :

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantorovich_theorem
https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.09791
Remark :

@MartinR we need to show that the derivative of $f(x)$ in absolute value doesn't vanish AFTER the positive real root of $f(x)$ for that we need a bound .
See [Under what conditions a rational function has bounded derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679783/under-what-conditions-a-rational-function-has-bounded-derivative)

To be continued.

Eurêka as there is only one positive real root we can apply [Gauss-Lucas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) theorem.

And so all the starting value $k>x_{positive-root}$ are OK

Comment: The Kantorovich theorem requires that *any* $x \in X$ has a neighborhood such that $(I)$ holds for $x, y \in I$ (with some constant $k$). It does not suffice that the condition holds for large $x, y$.

Comment: @MartinR I agree numerical evidence says but a more accurate explanation is needed as bound the derivative for example . Do you want to make an answer instead of just push remark without any help ?

Comment: @MartinR I have finished

Comment: The Gauss-Lukas theorem states that for a polynomial $P$, the roots of $P'$ are inside the convex hull of *all* roots of the roots of $P$ (including the non-real roots). So even if $P$ has only a single positive real root $x_0$ it is still possible that $P'(x) = 0$ for some $x > x_0$.

Comment: @MartinR again I agree but here all the variable are real which is sufficient.

Comment: $P(x) = (x-2)^3-x+4$ has a single real root $x_0 \approx 0.479 > 0$, and the derivative has two zeros at approx $1.423$ and $2.578$.

Comment: @MartinR I believe you but here the function is convex over$R_+$ so I stop here to answer you .

Comment: For convex functions the situation is quite simple: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2616498/42969. If your function is convex then we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinR nothing to do with a duplicate since I introduce $f(x)$ as rational function  .Cohn art.

Comment: @MartinR the function if convex it works if concave and next convex it's worst it's negative .

Comment: If proved we have a local inversion we can speak about Hasse principle and Jacobian conjecture with quadratic.